# Items required to publish after upgrading to DD4T 2.2 and Web 8.5

Tags: publishing, dd4t, web8.5, dd4t-2

After upgrading to DD4T .NET 2.2 and SDL Web 8.5 from DD4T 2.0 and Tridion 2013 SP1 we have found that few Pages are not showing images on the Page.

On most of the Pages, images are showing perfectly. When we published the Page in new Publication Target, Pages started to show images perfectly. So my question is, what all the CMS items required to publish after upgrading to DD4T 2.2 and SDL Web 8.5?

I believe upgrading to SDL Web 8.5 doesn't require any publishing but does DD4T 2.2 requires publishing after upgrading from DD4T 2.0? Please share if anyone analyzed it before.

Comment: Normally you do not need to republish after upgrading from DD4T 2.0 to 2.2. Did you see any errors (in the log or on the screen) when you had those problems with images?

Comment: There was neither error in the log file nor on screen. It was simply not showing on the page. When I published the page on new publication target it started showing.

Comment: Without a message it is hard to tell what could have been wrong. Perhaps the pages in question were really not published before. Did you change the name of the broker DB during the upgrade, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks @Quirijn. I didn't change the name of broker DB.

Comment: Do you still have links that don't work? Perhaps you can search for link_info on those components in the broker DB and make a screen shot of that. Then publish the component (so that the link works again), and search for the link_info again and make another screenshot. If both screenshots are the same, then it looks like there is something wrong in DD4T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was because of the use of a obsolete method in the application code. To show the images we were checking the last publish date and based on that there was some logic written in the code. In the code we were still using IBinaryFactory.FindLastPublishedDate(string) which was returning incorrect value. Once we change the code to use suggested method binaryFactory.FindBinaryMeta(urlPath) to get the binary meta and then binaryMeta.LastPublishedDate to get the last published date it started showing the images. So one thing we learnt that never ignore warning messages of obsolete methods in use after upgrade of website code.